# Could not initiate Hunspellx64.dll in Delphi

Tags: delphi, 64-bit, hunspell

I need to call Hunspell on 64 bit Delphi application. Hunspellx64.dllI is successfully loaded, but it fails to create a Hunspell instance:

```
procedure TForm5.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  HunLibHandle: THandle;
  fHunHandle: Pointer;
  Aff, Dic: TFileName;
begin
  HunLibHandle := LoadLibrary('Hunspellx64.dll');

  if HunLibHandle = 0 then
  begin
    ShowMessage('Error loading Hunspellx64.dll ');
    exit;
  end;

  Hunspell_create := THunspell_create(GetProcAddress(HunLibHandle, 'Hunspell_create'));
  if not Assigned(Hunspell_create) then
  begin
    ShowMessage('Error creating Hunspell ');
    exit;
  end;

  Aff := ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName) + 'en_US.aff';
  Dic := ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName) + 'en_US.dic';
  fHunHandle := Hunspell_create(pointer(Aff), pointer(Dic));

  ShowMessage('success');

  FreeLibrary(HunLibHandle);

end;
```

Could you please help me to resolve the problem?

Comment: What is THunSpell(_create)? It looks like your using 3rd party code that is not mentioned or shown here. Trace into that code to see what's going wrong.

Comment: THunspell_create = function(const affpath, dpath: PAnsiChar): Pointer; cdecl;

var
  Hunspell_create: THunspell_create;

  Form5: TForm5